# Readable view of json or xml in api response. Yii2

Tags: php, json, yii2

In guides response of api showing in readable view.  I want to understand, is it done only for showing structure of response, or there is a way to make readable view.

Examples in terminal:
my code: response in

```
"date_imported":"2016-03-19 18:30:22"}],"_links":{"self":{"href":"http://localhost/tweets?page=1"},"next":{"href":"http://localhost/tweets?page=2"},"last":{"href":"http://localhost/tweets?page=23"}},"_meta":{"totalCount":450,"pageCount":23,"currentPage":1,"perPage":20}}
```

docs: response at same code

```
"_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost/users?page=1"
        },
        "next": {
            "href": "http://localhost/users?page=2"
        },
        "last": {
            "href": "http://localhost/users?page=50"
        }
    },
    "_meta": {
        "totalCount": 1000,
        "pageCount": 50,
        "currentPage": 1,
        "perPage": 20
    }
}
```

Is it only for presentation, and actual response has string-view, or I something doing wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to parse the answer in a browser or in a client that formats the json output?

Comment: Ofcourse. Issue is different. In docs there is no parse, but the presentation of response in readble view. Same code from me, response is string-view.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to have a "readable" json response, you should simply modify [`$prettyPrint`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-jsonresponseformatter.html#$prettyPrint-detail) property of [`yii\web\JsonResponseFormatter`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-jsonresponseformatter.html) :

> `$prettyPrint` (available since version 2.0.7) : Whether to format the output in a readable "pretty" format.

To configure this property, you can configure the `response` application component like the following:

```
'response' => [
    'formatters' => [
        \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_JSON => [
             'class' => 'yii\web\JsonResponseFormatter',
             'prettyPrint' => YII_DEBUG, // use "pretty" output in debug mode
        ],
    ],
],
```